# What is the difference between 'eig' and 'eigs'?

Tags: matlab, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I've searched a lot for this but I can't find any answer about how the two methods 'eig' and 'eigs' differ. What is the difference between the eigenvalues and eigenvectors received from them?

Comment: This is probably not appropriate for this site, as it is primarily a question about the difference in two numerical algorithms to determine eigenvalues/vectors.

Comment: Note as of r2017b: the output order of `eigs` is different from `eig`. See [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=eigs&startrelease=R2015a&endrelease=R2017b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=eigs)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They use different algorithms, tailored to different problems and different goals.

`eig` is a good, fast, general use eigenvalue/vector solver. It is appropriate for use when your matrix is of a realistic size that fits well in memory, and when you need all of the eigenvalues/vectors. Sparse matrices do not work at all in `eig`.

Eigs is a solver that is more appropriate for when you need only a limited subset of the eigenvalues/vectors. Here the matrix is often stored in sparse format, because as a full matrix, it would take up too much memory to store. It appears that eigs is based on [ARPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK).

If you truly are asking for specifics on the actual algorithms, this is a question that is clearly inappropriate for this site. Sit down with a copy of "Matrix Computations", or better yet, read the pair of references listed in the doc for `eigs`.