# Are the largest eigenvectors sorted by absolute eigenvalue?

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Say I have a real symmetric matrix, and I want to extract the k largest eigenvectors using [`eig`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html).

I know I can use [`eigs`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) instead but that's not the point of my question. 
 I read that they use [different algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855798/472610), and the documentation for `eigs` states explicitly "*largest **magnitude***", which seems to imply that the eigenvalues would be sorted in *absolute value*, especially because apparently the sign of the eigenvector/values [does not matter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205715/44129).

However I also read that [ordering the eigenvectors](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/7950/15177) should be done according to the ranking of the eigenvalues, with `sort(diag(D))`; no absolute value here (and no assumption about positiveness for the matrix).

1. I think that either the latter post is wrong, or Matlab's documentation for `eigs` is wrong or misleading when using the words "largest magnitude", is that right? Or are they both right and I misunderstood something?
2. To clarify then, the "largest" eigenvectors should be sorted according to the *absolute* eigenvalue, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The latter question you reference is discussing `eig`, which uses direct methods intended for general, dense matrices; you are discussing `eigs`, which uses iterative methods intended for general, sparse matrices.

   `eig` will return the eigenvalues in the order found by the direct method.  In general, this means random ordering.  For real symmetric matrices, the ordering from the direct method appears to generate the eigenvalues from most negative to most positive.

   `eigs` will return `k` eigenvalues and vectors with the largest/smallest magnitude/real part/imaginary part (user-specified).  However, [as noted](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html#moreabout), "`eigs` does not always return sorted eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Use `sort` to explicitly sort the output eigenvalues and eigenvectors in cases where their order is important."
2. Typically, yes, largest (absolute) magnitude. Though `sort` can be used to permute the eigenvalues into any required order.

Comment: Thanks, my question was mainly to make sure about the "absolute" part.